# Double link on form post when working on Local Host

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

~

I have tried to create a form and submit the data using a method from a CI controller, but when I press submit the link just doubles as follows:

```
http://localhost/1xtask/index.php/auth/localhost/1xTask/auth/login
```

I am using Xampp. I have double checked the CI config file and the HTACCESS.

Config file relevant data:

`$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/1xTask/';`

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

HTACCESS file:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Still, I can't get it to work properly :(

Form action looks like this in browser: `<form action="localhost/1xTask/auth/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

I use `<?php echo form_open('auth/login'); ?>` and `<?php echo form_close(); ?>`  to create the form

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I did not understand what is your problem

Comment: Instead of having ``localhost/1xTask/auth/login`` i have the link  ``http://localhost/1xtask/index.php/auth/localhost/1xTask/auth/login``

Comment: write the code you use to create the link

Comment: @GiacomoM I edited the post with all you asked for. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure but I think you have to add an **`HTTP`** protocol to your
 **`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/1xTask/';`** and that might resolve your issue.

Comment: this was it! Thank you a lot! Marked your answer!